# Nuxt.js and Laravel Api - 422 Displaying Error instead of Forms

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

[Error][1]

[image]

Hi Team,

Whenever I am receiving the error return from laravel the nuxt.js project displays the error on the page instead the HTML/Forms. How can i handle this.
Here is my php code

```php
return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    'email' => ['Sorry we cant find you with those details.'],
                ],
            ], 422);
```

Javascript

```jscript
 async submit() {
                await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
                    data: this.form
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

In your JavaScript you need to wrap your `await` promise inside a `try catch` block. Here's a fix for your JS.

```
try {

  await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
    data: this.form
  })

} catch (e) {

  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you actually paste full code. I am trying this myself, and it seems to be not working. ```  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      await this.$auth
        .loginWith("local", {
          data: this.form
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.$router.push("/dashboard");
        })
        .catch(error => {});
    }
  },```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question at this point, but I thought I'd post the full code since I was pretty stumped and didn't find many great answers out there:

```js
async handleSubmit() {
    try {
        const authResponse = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { 
            data: this.formData
        });
        const { status, data } = authResponse;

        if (status === 200) 
            this.createFlashAlert({ 'success': 'Login successful' });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 422)
            this.createFlashAlert(error.response.data);
    }
}
```

So the checklist:

1. Wrap the login call in a try/catch if you're using async await syntax (be sure to make it an async function i.e. `async handleSubmit`.
2. in the catch block, use the `error.response` object, this is an axios thing. With this you'll be able to access the response `status` and `data`.

If you log just the `error` object, it's not obvious that you can access the response within that error which is what had me stumped.